# How to "help" a Dictionary performance with business logic knowledge

Tags: dictionary, data-structures

Let's say I have a Dictionary (in .NET) with keys from 1 to 100.
I know from my historical data that, say, 99% of the time I access this Dictionary to retrieve the data for keys 5, 37, 88.
Is there a way I can organize this dicionary so that it is very fast with these 3 keys, even at the expense of more time wasted in looking for the remaining 97 keys?
Or maybe is there a different data structure that could use this knowledge to improve the average time of access to data?

Answer (score 0):

In a reasonable implementation of a dictionary, the cost of a lookup will be dominated by the cost of a memory access. Your hardware will optimize this for you, leaving the most frequently accessed items in the fastest cache levels. 100 items will fit in your fastest cache unless you have a tiny computer.

That said, if you are using a hash table with separate chaining, you can move those items to the front of their chains. This ensures that looking up those items will be O(1) worst case guaranteed, whereas, for at least one item in your dictionary, lookup is O(log n/log log n) with high probability.

Of course, if you have only 100 keys, using a hash table rather than a dictionary will ensure that every key has O(1) worst-case access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a small cache in front of the dictionary, which could be faster. For example, if you know that most of your access are for items 3, 37, and 88, then you could have:

```
private Dictionary<int, MyDataType> TheDictionary;
private KeyValuePair<int, MyDataType>[] quickLookup;

void InitializeDictionary()
{
    TheDictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyDataType>();
    // here, initialize the dictionary with the data.

    // Now, set up the cache
    quickLookup = new KeyValuePair<int, MyDataType>[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair(3, TheDictionary[3]),
        new KeyValuePair(37, TheDictionary[37]),
        new KeyValuePair(88, TheDictionary[88])
    };
```

Now, when you want to look for an item, you first check the cache:

```
bool TryDictionaryLookup(int key, out MyDataType data)
{
    foreach (var kvp in quickLookup)
    {
        if (kvp.key == key)
        {
            data = kvp.Value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // didn't find it. Check the dictionary.
    return TheDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out data);
}
```

This should give you a *small* performance boost if your cache is only three items. If you get more than five or six items, though, it probably will perform worse than the straight dictionary lookup. You'd have to do some timings to determine where the sweet spot is.

Also note that, if you're really into this kind of micro-optimization, you probably should replace the `foreach` with a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < quickLookup.Length)
{
    if (quickLookup[i].Key == key)
    ...
    ...
```

That will eliminate the overhead of creating the enumerator.

The reason this technique should provide a performance boost is that accessing the dictionary requires computing a hash from the key. Whereas that's a fast operation, it's still more overhead than a few array accesses. Again, you'll want to thoroughly test and profile this with representative data before you put it in production.

The C# compiler uses (at least used to; I haven't checked in a while) something similar when generating code for `switch` statements. If the `switch` contains fewer than some number cases (I think it was six, last time I checked), then the compiler generates a series of `if/else` statements. For six or more items, it generates a dictionary of keys and branch locations, and code to lookup the case value in a dictionary and branch to the relevant code.